# How can I get neighbor country of a country?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

In my work, i need to find the attributes like currency, population etc neighbor country of a country From dbpedia.How can I do this? 
A solution may be like this..
A sparql query which get the longitude and latitude of all the countries from dbpedia and find the countries which cordinates are close to Germany.How about that? But I am new to sparql? So, I am not sure, how will be the query for this?

FYI:I do not need all the neighbours. Three neighbors is enough for me.

Comment: Are you only interested in neighbor countries of Germany (in that case you don't need DBpedia, I can tell you right now) or was that just a randomly mentioned example?

Comment: That's just an example

Answer (score 1):

By only querying dbpedia, it is not possible to get the neighbor country. The easiest way may be, get the longitude and latitudesfind the distance by a mathematical equation. the following is the java implantation of getting the distance

```
private double getDistance(double submittedCountryLat,double submittedCountryLong,double countryLat,double countryLong){

        double distance = 0;
        double submittedCountryLatRadian=Math.toRadians(submittedCountryLat);       
        double submittedCountryLongRadian=Math.toRadians(submittedCountryLong);
        double countryLatRadian=Math.toRadians(countryLat);
        double countryLongRadian=Math.toRadians(countryLong);

        double absoluteDistanceLat=submittedCountryLatRadian-countryLatRadian;
        double absoluteDistanceLong=submittedCountryLongRadian-countryLongRadian;

        distance=Math.sin(absoluteDistanceLat/2)*Math.sin(absoluteDistanceLat/2) +
                Math.cos(submittedCountryLatRadian)*Math.cos(countryLatRadian)* Math.sin(absoluteDistanceLong/2)*Math.sin(absoluteDistanceLong/2);

        distance=2* Math.asin(Math.sqrt(distance));
        return distance*6371;

    }
```

Then sort all the distance with the country name and take country name with the shortest distance